# Selected security alerts

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, security, drupal

I manage a series of web servers which host a myriad of CMS's. Wordpress, Drupal, CodeIgniter, ExpressionEngine, etc.

Is there a place I can get only the urgent security patch release alerts? websecuritywatch.com is great, but its a firehose.

Even better if it could be on just the platforms I have to support, but not others; I'd be happy to build my own Yahoo Pipe if I could find the right RSS feeds.

For example

- Wordpress 4.0.2 is released
- Timthumb2 discovered, affecting > 25% of Wordpress instances
- Drupal 7.33 is released

Comment: For WordPress, you can subscribe to the mailing list on the following link : https://wordpress.org/download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe the drupal security feed here:
https://www.drupal.org/security/rss.xml

Security infos can also be found on the drupal security website: https://www.drupal.org/security